# How to use the Tableselect element for an order-able list of items?

Tags: forms, 9

It's been a minute since I have used tableselect. I want to present a user with a list of sortable options that have checkboxes to indicate they are on or off. See this screenshot:

[image]

While the table does allow to drag options around, when the widget form is submitted the form values have already floated the selected options to the top with the unselected options to the bottom.

What I want to do is preserve the entire list, so I can set the correct order of the form the next time it is displayed in a form. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up following some examples set in this module to implement it in my code:

https://www.drupal.org/project/options_table

It seems like reading around that people do not advise using tableselect element to do this.

The result:

[image]

Users can store field level instance data, retaining order and other settings.